# How to encrypt data so that even admin can't access it?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, encryption, ruby-on-rails-4, cryptography, encryption-symmetric

I have a rails application where I have users who are either owner or staff. The users belong to different organizations. Owner or staff can store data in a common table of the database. But the data that they entered should be accessible to only the owner (using a key or something) though even the staff should be able to store data. I don't know how I should go about implementing this system.

One possible way I thought of was to provide a key to the owner and the staff/owner using it to store data and retrieve it and use symmetric encryption to store/retrieve data. But this will require that both staff as well as owner have the key. Does anyone know a better way to tackle this problem.

Comment: This sounds like something that calls for an asymmetric system. However, implementing your own security systems and protocols from cryptographic primitives is notoriously difficult, and even experts with 10 years of experience in the field don't always get it right. Somebody once said that programming crypto is like arming a bomb.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps: Within the appropriate controller, for the index and show actions (assuming you do CRUD)

```
    http_basic_authenticate_with name: "dhh", password: "secret", except: :index
```

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/HttpAuthentication/Basic.html

Or: Create a different user that has role "owner" and do authorization